# How to zoom Google Map accordingly on a returned result from Places API?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-places-api

I am currently trying to achieve to fluent zoom animations, that Google Maps has, where if the user searches for a city, for example, the map zooms enough, so he can see the entire city, and if he searches for a country the zoom is much larger. I have currently reached the point of getting the Place object, with its LatLng data, but have not found a way to zoom properly for a given search.

As far as I found out it should be done by supplying a southwest and northeast point to a RectangularBounds object and setting it to the map, but have not found a way to accomplish this with the Android API

Comment: I believe Places API should return view port for each item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [`Place.getViewport()`](https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/reference/com/google/android/libraries/places/api/model/Place.html#getViewport()) method from [Places SDK for Android](https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/reference/com/google/android/libraries/places/api/model/Place) to get a viewport ( [`LatLngBounds`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/LatLngBounds.html)) of a size that is suitable for displaying and then use it in [`animateCamera()`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.html#animateCamera(com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdate,%20com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.CancelableCallback)) or [`moveCamera()`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.html#moveCamera(com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdate)) methods. Something like that:

```
// get place from places API response
Place place = places.get(0);

int padding = 0; // padding  in pixels
LatLngBounds = bounds place.getViewport();
if (bounds != null) {
    CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds, padding);
    googleMap.animateCamera(cameraUpdate);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the input, this is exactly what I needed !